# Visual Studio 2022 opening Bing.com on Shift-F12

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I have a new installation of VS2022 (Current). If I right click on some C# code it will show "Find All References (Shift-F12)". Clicking on it will work. However, if I actually press `Shift-F12`, it will open an embedded browser window pointing to [www.bing.com](http://www.bing.com). If I go to Tools/Options/Keyboard, select "Press Shortcut Keys" and press `Shift-F12` it opens up the windows search screen rather than telling me what it's bound to within VS2022.

Any ideas how to diagnose or, preferable, stop this behaviour and revert to `Shift-F12` doing "Find All References"?

Answer (score 0):

So the answer to this one is on the weird side. Turns out I started using a bluetooth keyboard on the same day as starting to use Visual Studio 2022. The bluetooth keyboard treats the function keys as meta commands whilst the laptop keyboard does not. F12, of course, is "Open Search". To complicate matters, it turns out that Visual Studio 2022 intercepts this command. Whilst normally it opens up the Windows Search window, while in VS2022 in regular mode it instead starts an embedded web browser within Visual Studio. Not sure why you'd *want* that behaviour, but it does it.

The solution is to reconfigure your bluetooth keyboard.